# File Server Upload Python

Tags: python, file, upload, server, client

**File Server Download Problem Python 2.5.1**

So i am working on a File Server as a hobby project. I am having some problems though. I can use the client to successfully upload the file to the server but say the file to upload is 50,000 bytes (50 mbs) it will only upload like 49,945 bytes then if i try opening it, it says its corrupt. If i close the server it goes to 50,000 then works. Is there a way to fix this without the server needing to close and reopen?

(Downloading Doesnt Have this Problem)

Full Client Code:
[Client](http://pastebin.com/P2gCqwJM)

Full Server:
[Server](http://pastebin.com/14KwSxyf)

Client Upload Function:

```
def Uploader(s):
    IsReal = True
    data = "UploaderReady"
    if data == "UploaderReady":
        List = []
        FilePath = dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        List.append(os.listdir(FilePath))
        FileUpload = raw_input("Pick a file? -> ")
        for Item in List:
            if FileUpload == Item:
                IsReal = True #checks if item exists
        if IsReal == True:
            File = open(FileUpload,'rb')
            bytestosend = File.read(1024)
            FileSize = os.path.getsize(FileUpload)
            s.send(FileUpload)
            s.send(str(FileSize))
            s.send(bytestosend)
            while bytestosend != "":
                bytestosend = File.read(8192)
                s.send(bytestosend)
            print"Processing"
            File.close()
            time.sleep(1.5)
            s.send("COMPLETE")
            print"File Successfully Uploaded"
            time.sleep(2)
            print"    \n    " * 10
            Main()
        if IsReal == "False":
            print"Item doesn't Exist"
            time.sleep(2)
            print"    \n    " * 10
            s.close()
            Main()
```

Server Upload Function:

```
Todo = sock.recv(1024)
if Todo == "U":
    print str(addr)+" Uploading"
    UploadingThread = threading.Thread(target=Uploader,args=(c,c,))
    UploadingThread.start()

def Uploader(c,s):
    filename = s.recv(1024)
    filesize = s.recv(1024)
    f = open(filename,'wb')
    totalRecv = 0
    while totalRecv < filesize:
        FileContent = s.recv(8192)
        totalRecv += len(FileContent)
        f.write(FileContent)
    print"Download Complete"
    f.close()
    s.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried with smaller files?

Comment: Try closing the socket when you are done uploading on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the client connection on the server side, but never close it on the client side as [Cory Shay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6061947/cory-shay) said.
Instead of closing it though, you need to `shutdown` the socket and signal it is done writing with [`s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown)

Here's how it should look for the client:

```
def Uploader(s):
    IsReal = True
    data = "UploaderReady"
    if data == "UploaderReady":
        List = []
        FilePath = dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        List.append(os.listdir(FilePath))
        FileUpload = raw_input("Pick a file? -> ")
        for Item in List:
            if FileUpload == Item:
                IsReal = True #checks if item exists
        if IsReal == True:
            File = open(FileUpload,'rb')
            bytestosend = File.read(1024)
            FileSize = os.path.getsize(FileUpload)
            s.send(FileUpload)
            s.send(str(FileSize))
            s.send(bytestosend)
            while bytestosend != "":
                bytestosend = File.read(8192)
                s.send(bytestosend)
                print"Processing"
            s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) # End the writing stream
            print(s.recv(1024)) # Expecting the server to say 'upload complete'
            s.close() # close the socket
            File.close()
            time.sleep(1.5)
            s.send("COMPLETE")
            s.close() #To close connection after uploading
            print"File Successfully Uploaded"
            time.sleep(2)
            print"    \n    " * 10
            Main()
```

and the server:

```
def Uploader(c,s):
    filename = s.recv(1024)
    filesize = s.recv(1024)
    f = open(filename,'wb')
    totalRecv = 0
    while totalRecv < filesize:
        FileContent = s.recv(8192)
        totalRecv += len(FileContent)
        f.write(FileContent)
    s.send("Upload Complete!") # Tell client the upload is complete
    print"Download Complete"
    f.close()
    s.close() # Close the socket
```

Also, you are passing the server `Uploader` 2 identical arguments, and only using one, instead you should just pass one:

```
UploadingThread = threading.Thread(target=Uploader,args=(c,c,))
# should be
UploadingThread = threading.Thread(target=Uploader,args=(c,))
```

Similarly, your password thread only needs 2:

```
c, addr = s.accept()
print"Client Connection: <"+str(addr)+">"
PasswordThread = threading.Thread(target=Password,args=(c,addr))

def Password(c,addr):
    c.send("WAITINGPASSWORD")
    PASSWORD = "123"
    password = c.recv(1024)
```

and your checking password function can be simpler:

```
def Password(c,addr):
    password = "123"
    c.send("WAITINGPASSWORD")
    attempt = c.recv(1024)[::-1]
    if attempt == password:
        doStuff()
```

Comment: Thanks Xander Luciano. it almost worked. but it gets stuck at s.send("Upload Complete!") It may be cause im on python 2.5.1 and not python 3. You asked "Have you tried smaller files?" i did like 500 kbs it didnt work i still needed to close the server. if you could have a revised answer that would be great.

Comment: If this answer helped, you should upvote or accept the answer. No other answers have been posted in 4 days so maybe consider posting a new question if you have further issues. @Rogocraft